# Rails ActiveRecord::Relation object using including models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to retrieve information from two separate models which are similar but not the same. I am trying to do things like

I have looked into a few methods however they return an array of active objects rather than an 
 ActiveRecord::Relation which is required for many of the features of my app to work.

Is there any way to return an ActiveRecord::Relation object containing a union of both tables?

I have tried things like

```
@group = Mymodel.find_by_sql("SELECT id FROM Mymodels 
  UNION SELECT id FROM AnotherModels")
```

and also explored using the Model.where method however cannot return an ActiveRecord::Relation

EDIT:

Just to be clear I need to return ActiveRecord::Relation that is a union or a merge of the two tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `MyFirstModel.joins(:my_second_models)`? Check out details `joins` in the API [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

EDIT: Single Table Inheritance is a better solution to this problem. See comments below.

Comment: Hey, thanks but not sure this is what Im looking for. I don't want to join the two tables together though I need to return a record containing all of the objects of both models. Tis more like union

Comment: Ah, I understand your problem better now. I think you should look into Single Table Inheritance: creating two models based off the same database table. That way you can pull everything out easily with associations, but you can create unique attributes and methods for each model.

Comment: Cool I had looked into this but was hoping there would be a simpler way as I am extending an existing application. Plus there will be quite a lot of null columns. But seems like it might be the only way

Comment: Two options to deal with the null columns: create a `has_one` association with all the 'extra' columns so they can be stored in another table, or create a text `data` column and `serialize :data`, which will allow you to store addition attributes in a hash (downside: you won't be able to use SQL to search them). Alternatively, you can worry about efficiency later when you have enough volume (that's my solution of choice!)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Model.joins(:other_model).where("attr1" = :attr1,
                               { attr1: "example" }).group(:attr1)
```

Since you commented about `where`, I added the `where` method on the call. You can also group everything using `:group` in the end.